# Connecting SMP Server (on SAP HANA Cloud Platform Mobile Services) with Netweaver end point

Tags: odata, sap-gateway, sap-smp

I am mobile iOS developer and need a demo environment while making a Proof Of Concept app that will run against SAP Mobile Platform 3.0 (SMP) and Netweaver Endpoint using OData service. I need to be testing against SMP Server 3.0 SP05 or SP06 as I need to work with Offline mode as well.

I have setup SAP HANA Cloud Platform Mobile Services on CAL (https://cal.sap.com), configured my application and can successfully execute user registration and on-boarding against the SMP. I am using one of SAP-provided Netweaver demo endpoints, but then I am getting http errors when further making HTTP requests from SMP to the Netweaver endpoint.

The SMP uses HTTPS protocol.

The Netweaver demo endpoint is at https://sapes1.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/

It gives me errors like:

`Unable to extract request URI: URI must contain a port: https://hcpms-p1941221453trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/com.sap.flight/`

or

`Cannot open tunnel with id account:///p1941221453trial`

or

`HTTPS proxying is not supported. Use HTTP instead. HTTPS is not needed because communication is already secured by the tunnel.`

Can somebody please sugest the correct configuration of the end point - Authentication Type, Rewrite Mode, Proxy Type - to get the SMP working with the demo endpoint?

If it is not possible to connect to this NW endpoint from HANA Cloud SMP, can you please sugest another way how to get a demo NW Endpoint with one of SAP sample OData applications? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you for a subset of your issues:

Regarding the HTTPS error, have a look here:
https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?9d0e9e8397f544d9a5de5df52fd1e757.html

It mentions: The communication between the XS application and the proxy listening on localhost is always via HTTP. Whether the connection to the on-premise back-end should be HTTP or HTTPS is a matter of access control configuration in the Cloud connector. For more information, see Configuring Access Control (HTTP).

Basically, when something goes through the Cloud Connector, the HANA server uses a the proxy localhost:20003 in HTTP